# How to modify the SharePoint Online List field names for every language?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, localization, language-pack

SharePoint Online List "Display name" - Not the same for everyone (Localization)

Hello Guys,

My co-worker changed the name of a SharePoint Online list field (via list settings, not the quick editor) but the new name shows only for him.

I have run the following command via PowerShell

```
Get-PnPField -List LSIT -Identity "FIELDID" | Select *
```

My results:

```
SchemaXml: <Field Type="Boolean" DisplayName="Old name" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" Indexed="FALSE" ID="{FIELDID}" SourceID="{LISTID}" StaticName="Old_x0020_name" Name="Old_x0020_name" ColName="bit17" RowOrdinal="0" Version="6" Required="FALSE" CustomFormatter=""><Default>0</Default></Field>
StaticName: Old_x0020_name
Title: Old name
```

My co-worker's result

```
SchemaXml: <Field Type="Boolean" DisplayName="Old name" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" Indexed="FALSE" ID="{FIELDID}" SourceID="{LISTID}" StaticName="Old_x0020_name" Name="Old_x0020_name" ColName="bit17" RowOrdinal="0" Version="6" Required="FALSE" CustomFormatter=""><Default>0</Default></Field>
StaticName: Old_x0020_name
Title: NEW NAME
```

Today I have noticed that my co-worker is using the English localization settings.

Because of this I decided to research the method of the localization in the SharePoint

https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/exporttranslations.aspx 
(to import use _layouts/importtranslations.aspx)

I have exported both the English and the Hungarian version and I find that there is difference.

So my Question is how to change the SharePoint Online List field names for every language?

Answer (score 0):

Try this PnP commands (https://github.com/pnp/PnP-PowerShell/releases)

```
Connect-PnPOnline –Url https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/site –Credentials (Get-Credential)
Set-PnPField -Identity OldFieldName -Values @{Title="NewFieldName"} -UpdateExistingLists
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is only modifies the logged in user's localization. (This does the same If I modify via the list settings)